# ZF2 Translation

Tags: zend-framework2, translation

I have two modules - Application and StickyNotes. I need to use translation on all pages.

What I do:

1) In view: `<?=$this->translate('Home');?>`

2) In Application\Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'setLayoutTitle'));
    $translator->setLocale('ru_RU');
    echo $translator->getLocale(); //ru_RU
}
```

3) In StickyNotes\Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $translator->setLocale('ru_RU');
    echo $translator->getLocale(); //ru_RU
}
```

4) Application\..\module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),

'aliases' => array(
    'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
),

'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

5) StickyNotes\..\module.config.php same:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),

'aliases' => array(
    'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
),

'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

If i try `$translator->getLocale();` output 'ru_RU', but translation don`t work.

Also, if I manually change  `'locale' => 'en_US',` to `'locale' => 'ru_RU',`
translation work fine. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Did you try to remove 'locale' => 'en_US' in module.config.php?

Comment: No idea if it's related, but your `aliases` array should be inside the `service_manager` array

Comment: If I remove 'locale', I have this exception `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\I18n\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException' with message 'Zend\I18n\Translator component requires the intl PHP extension`.  About `aliases` - if I add in `service_manager`, displayed error - aliases already included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Application\Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
            $lang = $e->getRequest()->getQuery('lang'); // new language
            $session = new Container('base');
            if($lang == null && $lang == ''){
                if ($session->offsetExists('lang')) {
                    $lang = $session->offsetGet('lang'); // current language
                }else{
                    $lang = Settings::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE; // default language
                }
            }
            $session->offsetSet('lang', $lang);
            $loc = Settings::$locations[$lang];
            $translator
            ->setLocale($loc)
            ->setFallbackLocale(Settings::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE .'_' . Settings::DEFAULT_LOCATION);
    }
```

and Settings class

```
class Settings{
   const DEFAULT_LOCATION =  'IR';
   const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'fa';

   public static $locations = array(
        'fa'=>'fa_IR',
            'sa'=>'sa_SA',//Arabic (sa, sa-SA)
        'tr'=>'tr_TR',
        'en'=>'en_US'
    );
}
```

Comment: Solved, thank you. I removed 
`'factories' => array('translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',),` 

and all translations works fine.

Answer (score 1):

put translator config only in Application\module.config.php and be sure you have language folder in Application module and put *.mo and *.po file on that .

in the fact , you don't need to set locale in each module . only put in Application\Module.php

in poedit Catalog->properties->Sources keywords-> check "translate" word exist and it's better that be first.

at the end , `<?=$this->translate('Home');?>` deprecated . use
 `<?php echo $this->translate('Home');?>`

**update 1:** 
sorry , this code `<?=$this->translate('Home');?>` not deprecated but PHP manual recommendation is  `<?php echo $this->translate('Home');?>`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: I tried to do everything that you said but the translation is still not working. I don`t know how well this solution but for me its working:  In bootstrap
 
`$viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();

 $viewModel->language = $session->offsetGet('lang');`

In view: `<?= $this->translate('Home', 'default', $language); ?>`

Comment: what's mea that?!? $viewModel->language = $session->offsetGet('lang');

Comment: Put language view model from session.

Comment: Actually as of php 5.4 <?= ... ?> is supported! http://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/1594076

Comment: `<?=`  works independently of php 5+ version. It works only if in php.ini enable otion `"Open_short_tag"`. Also, if i change to `<?php echo` it still doesnt work...

Comment: @Walllter for versions < 5.4 that is correct but since 5.4 `<?=` is supported everywhere regardless of php.ini open_short_tag setting. But `<?=` is NOT deprecated like @amin arab suggested, it is actually becoming fundamental. The comment was not about the solution, if you have php 5.4+ or open_short_tags on `<?=` and `<?php echo` are the same so it does not affect your code.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the absence of intl extension

So just required these steps:

I had to install PHP Intl extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Apache Restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Check what extension compiled:

```
php -m
```